# How to find the minimum in an array excluding 0?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, minimum

I have an array with some values, and I want to find the minimum value of that array in order to print out the index that this value has. In this array, one of the values is 0. My guess is that in order to find the index, we must iterate through this array find the minimum, but not the 0, and return the index. Can you help me understand what I am doing wrong with the iterations? I cannot find the minimum number.

This is the array:

```
[ 10, 5, 6, 5.5, 3.75, 0, 4.25, 3, 5.5, 6.75, 8, 9.25, 4, 15, 4.25, 6, 6, 4.75, 3.75 ]
```

I am currently stuck here:

```
  var smallest = 0
    var biggest = 0

    for (let i = 0; i < merged.length; i++) {


        if (merged[i] > biggest && merged[i] != 0) {
            biggest = merged[i];

        } else merged[i] < smallest ? smallest = merged[i] : smallest = merged[i];



        console.log('the biggest is', biggest, 'in the iteration', i)
        console.log('the smallest is', smallest, 'in the iteration', i)
    }


    console.log('min-> : ', smallest, biggest);
```

That gives this:

```
the biggest is 10 in the iteration 0
the smallest is 0 in the iteration 0
the biggest is 10 in the iteration 1
**the smallest is 5 in the iteration 1**
the biggest is 10 in the iteration 2
**the smallest is 6 in the iteration 2**
the biggest is 10 in the iteration 3
the smallest is 5.5 in the iteration 3
the biggest is 10 in the iteration 4
the smallest is 3.75 in the iteration 4
the biggest is 10 in the iteration 5
the smallest is 0 in the iteration 5
the biggest is 10 in the iteration 6
the smallest is 4.25 in the iteration 6
the biggest is 10 in the iteration 7
the smallest is 3 in the iteration 7
the biggest is 10 in the iteration 8
the smallest is 5.5 in the iteration 8
the biggest is 10 in the iteration 9
the smallest is 6.75 in the iteration 9
the biggest is 10 in the iteration 10
the smallest is 8 in the iteration 10
the biggest is 10 in the iteration 11
the smallest is 9.25 in the iteration 11
the biggest is 10 in the iteration 12
the smallest is 4 in the iteration 12
the biggest is 15 in the iteration 13
the smallest is 4 in the iteration 13
the biggest is 15 in the iteration 14
the smallest is 4.25 in the iteration 14
the biggest is 15 in the iteration 15
the smallest is 6 in the iteration 15
the biggest is 15 in the iteration 16
the smallest is 6 in the iteration 16
the biggest is 15 in the iteration 17
the smallest is 4.75 in the iteration 17
the biggest is 15 in the iteration 18
the smallest is 3.75 in the iteration 18
min-> :  3.75 15
```

As you can see above, the smallest should not change from `5` to `6`. The minimum should be `3`.

Thank you very much.

***Question solved, thank you all for your time and help !!***

Comment: What do you mean by `merged[i] < smallest ? smallest = merged[i] : smallest = merged[i]`?

Comment: @Autumnal_Joy I am asking if the current number of the array is smaller than the variable 'smallest' and if yes, I assign the current number as the smaller so far in the iteration.

Comment: But whatever `merged[i] < smallest` is true or false, `smallest = merged[i]` will be executed. If it is true, the one before ":" is executed, otherwise the latter one is executed.

Comment: You DO NOT CHECK for zero in the smallest! You check it in the biggest. Unclear why you are using a ternary and not doing an else if like you do for the biggest.

Comment: @Autumnal_Joy I see , i will try to solve it with this way also. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @espascarello Thank you for your points. I was trying to accomplish that for a lot of hours, and it didn't work. That is why I tried also with this way. I need more work to understand what and why is a better solution. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change your code to the following,

```
var smallest = 0;
var biggest = 0;
var merged = [ 10, 5, 6, 5.5, 3.75, 0, 4.25, 3, 5.5, 6.75, 8, 9.25, 4, 15, 4.25, 6, 6, 4.75, 3.75 ];

    for (let i = 0; i < merged.length; i++) {

        if (merged[i] > biggest && merged[i] != 0) {
            biggest = merged[i];
        }

        if(smallest == 0 || (merged[i] < smallest && merged[i] != 0)) {
            smallest = merged[i];
        }

        console.log('the biggest is', biggest, 'in the iteration', i)
        console.log('the smallest is', smallest, 'in the iteration', i)
    }
```

I assumed you no need to check the index of 0 valued item in the array.

Comment: Indeed, simple as that… Amazing..  @Dui , thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Fast question @Dui Samarasinghe for your code solution. In the second `if` we first check the code in side the `()` that means : if the current value of the array is smaller than `smallest` value, but also the current value of the array is not 0 then the current value of the array is the smallest one for this iteration. I can't translate the first part `smallest == 0`. How we can say that in plain English, please? Thank you very much.

Comment: smallest == 0 this part added to make smallest=merged[0] with first iteration. You can add it before the loop also.

Comment: Got it , thank you, @Dui Samarasinghe

Answer (score 1):

You can first find the min without zero then find the index using the following, this can be changed to also find the maximum index.

```js
const arr = [ 10, 5, 6, 5.5, 3.75, 0, 4.25, 3, 5.5, 6.75, 8, 9.25, 4, 15, 4.25, 6, 6, 4.75, 3.75 ]
const minIndex = arr.indexOf(Math.min.apply(null, arr.filter(Boolean)))
console.log(minIndex)
```

Here's an iterative approach incase it is clearer:

```js
const findMin = (arr) => {
  let min;

  for(let i =0; i < arr.length; i++){
      if(!min && arr[i]!==0) min = arr[i]
      if(arr[i] < min && arr[i]!==0) min = arr[i]
  }
  return arr.indexOf(min)
}
const arr = [ 10, 5, 6, 5.5, 3.75, 0, 4.25, 3, 5.5, 6.75, 8, 9.25, 4, 15, 4.25, 6, 6, 4.75, 3.75 ]
console.log(findMin(arr))
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Safder for your answer, but it gives the index 5 which is the 0. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Using the code above? I've tested it using your test case and it returns 7

Comment: Unbelievable @Safder , let me try again..

Comment: @GeorgeMoraitis I've updated the test case above such that you can run it yourself on your test case

Comment: Finally, worked !! Thank you, @Safder very much your time.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your failed function, it is reporting the current iteration but it appears it doesn't keep track of each iteration or better yet it should carry the most minimal number in each iteration.

- Spread the array with `...` operator
- `.filter()` array straight through and it will return truthy values which excludes 0.
- Then use `Math.min()`
- Finally, get the index with `.indexOf()`

```js
let data = [ 10, 5, 6, 5.5, 3.75, 0, 4.25, 3, 5.5, 6.75, 8, 9.25, 4, 15, 4.25, 6, 6, 4.75, 3.75 ];

let out = data.indexOf(Math.min(...data.filter(n => n)))

console.log(out);
```

Comment: Amazing, it gives me ```-1``` @zer00ne , i will keep trying..

Comment: What gives you a -1? @GeorgeMoraitis

Comment: Awesome!!!!!  When you want the most maximum `Math.max()` of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can scan the array only once to find the minimum as well as the index.

```
var merged = [
  10, 5, 6, 5.5, 3.75, 0, 4.25, 3, 5.5, 6.75, 8, 9.25, 4, 15, 4.25, 6, 6, 4.75,
  3.75,
];

let [minVal, minIndex] = merged.reduce(
  function ([minVal, minIndex], currentVal, currentIndex) {
    if (currentVal!= 0 && minVal > currentVal) {
      minVal = currentVal;
      minIndex = currentIndex;
    }
    return [minVal, minIndex];
  },
  [Infinity, -1]
);

console.log(minVal, minIndex);
```

Also, it works.

```
var merged = [
  10, 5, 6, 5.5, 3.75, 0, 4.25, 3, 5.5, 6.75, 8, 9.25, 4, 15, 4.25, 6, 6, 4.75,
  3.75,
];

var smallest = Infinity;

for (let i = 0; i < merged.length; i++) {
  if (merged[i] < smallest && merged[i] != 0) {
    smallest = merged[i];
  }
  console.log("the smallest is", smallest, "in the iteration", i);
}

console.log("min-> : ", smallest);
```

Comment: Thank you very much  @Autumnal_Joy for your code solution , i am currently studying each one of the solutions. I was stuck to this problem 2 days now. I need more work..